# Set value of $scope after selecting filter options in AngularJs MVC 4

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-scope

I am using AngularJS to bind the data at client side. Currently I am displaying top 100 rows which works fine on page load. Now I want to get filter conditions from user, retrieve fresh rows from server and bind it again. How can I reload new data from server on event `onclick="RefreshUsers()"` How to update value of `$scope.Users` again from serer and refresh the div?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function customersController($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("/home/GetUserDetails").success(function (response) { 
           $scope.Users = response; 
        });
    }
</script>

   <input name="btnRefreshUsers" id="btnRefreshUsers" type="submit" 
                onclick="RefreshUsers()" value="Refresh users list">

    <br/>
    <div id='result' data-ng-app='' data-ng-controller='customersController'>
  <table>
            <tr data-ng-repeat='x in users | orderBy : 'UserId''>
                <td>
                    {{ x.UserId }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ x.UserName }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ x.MobileNo }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function customersController($scope, $http) {

// ADD THIS METHOD
     $scope.RefreshUsers = function() {
        var url = "/home/GetUserDetails?search="+$scope.refreshModel;
        $http.get(url).success(function (response) { 
           $scope.Users = response; 
        });
     }

}
```

AND

```
<input name="btnRefreshUsers" id="btnRefreshUsers" type="submit" ng-model="refreshModel"
            ng-click="RefreshUsers()" value="Refresh users list">
```

check with these two modifications

Comment: It throws error "JavaScript runtime error: 'RefreshUsers' is undefined"

Comment: edited my answer please check use `ng-click` instead `onClick`

Comment: calling server side is working but data is not refreshing after execution. I am missing something?

Comment: can u get the data from server from calling serverside ?

Comment: Yes data is coming properly but its not reflecting in data-ng-controller="customersController"

Comment: in your controller `$scope.Users = response;` // capital (U)sers . But in `ng-repeat` simple 'u'sers . try to use `users` for both places